# How to write to flat file destination from recordset object?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have the following requirements for a SSIS package which writes to flat file destinations:

- Accept a parameter that will determine the file format (CSV, TSV, Fixed Width)
- Accept a parameter that determines the maximum number of records per file, e.g., if I return 100000 records and the maximum number of records per file is 25000, I need to create 4 files.

This is all well and good until we get to this requirement:

- Before any file is actually written, call a web service for each record found and pass in the recordId and a particular message.

Previous to this latest requirement, my approach was to populate a staging table, get the min and max recordIds for each export batch, then use a Loop control flow (Number of Records in RecordSet / MaxNumberOfRecordsPerFile) to then use a Data Flow Task to select the particular range of records and write them to each file. The downside to this is that I know have to have 3 different Data Flow Tasks (one for each particular file format), each with a call to the database. With the new requirement, I'd have to make yet another call to the database to get the entire record set, not just the iterative portion.

What I would like to do is make one call to get the entire record set, load it into a RecordSet destination object variable, then loop through that, so I don't have to have so many database calls. However, I can't figure out how to use a RecordSet object variable (or any variable) as a data source in the data flow task. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Heres an old post with some ideas - http://mgarner.wordpress.com/2006/04/14/ssis-recordset-destination-as-source/

Comment: Have a look of this thread -  http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2007/10/14/ssis-design-pattern-read-a-dataset-from-variable-in-a-script-task.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Get Execute SQL Task for your query result, set ResultSet property to Full result set. Under Result Set pane, Add variable of object type.  Add Script Task and connect Execute SQL Task to it. In script task editor, set ReadWriteVariables to object variable of SQL Task. In script you can access data from object variable as:

```
Dim oleDA As New OleDbDataAdapter
  Dim dt As New DataTable
  Dim col As DataColumn
  Dim row As DataRow
  Dim sMsg As String

  oleDA.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables("dsObjVar").Value)

  For Each row In dt.Rows
   For Each col In dt.Columns
    sMsg = sMsg & col.ColumnName & ": " & _
           row(col.Ordinal).ToString & vbCrLf
   Next
   MsgBox(sMsg)
   sMsg = ""
  Next

  Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
```

and `dt`   can be processed as regular DataTable.